# How to add admin using flask_pymongo and flask_admin

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, flask-admin

How to add admin using flask_pymongo and flask_admin

```

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

from bson import json_util

from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import flask_admin as admin

from wtforms import form, fields

from flask_admin.form import Select2Widget
from flask_admin.contrib.pymongo import ModelView, filters
from flask_admin.model.fields import InlineFormField, InlineFieldList
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

# app settings
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://username:passwrod@ds156811.mlab.com:56811/somedb'
app.config['MONGO_CONNECT'] = True
app.secret_key = 'secret'

mongo = PyMongo(app)
db = mongo


class UserForm(form.Form):
    name = fields.StringField('Name')
    email = fields.StringField('Email')

class UserView(ModelView):
    column_list = ('name', 'email')
    form = UserForm

admin = admin.Admin(app)


admin.add_view(UserView(db['users']))
```

```

Here is small example taken from https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.9/db_pymongo/
Here is another:
https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/tree/master/examples/pymongo

The flask-admin community has used `pymongo` but I want to use flask-pymongo package.

I am okay with most of the code but adding of view to the admin page is creating problem, `admin.add_view()` function is creating problem.

The question is **how to add view to admin page, by taking flask-admin and flask-pymongo(pymongo is different)?**

**Edited**:
error message:

```
TypeError: 'PyMongo' object is not subscriptable
```

The object we get using the pymongo is different from what we get from pyflask-mongo, which is being responsible for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the following changes will help, these are in fact just comments on your question but due to low rep, I can't comment.

```
import flask_admin as admin
```

I would not import this as admin because of the following line at the end:

```
admin = admin.Admin(app)
```

Try the following instead:

```
from flask_admin import Admin
```

and then on the bottom line:

```
admin = Admin(app)
```

In this way you are not using `admin` for multiple things which might be an issue.

EDIT:

The TypeError is causing a problem because of the Pymongo object not being a subscriptable object so can you change the last code to this, found this in the flask_admin docs :

```
admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
```

Comment: This ain't working my friend, the problem is particular on adding view in the admin page.... the last line in the code, IMO is fine.

Comment: can you post your errors, you are getting? might be easier to find a solution then.

Comment: the problem is indeed in this line: `admin.add_view(UserView(db['users']))` but the problem is with the argument you give to UserView. You can not use db['users'] since db is not a dict. I will updated my answer with some code since it is too long to write here

Comment: did any of the changes helped you yet @gurditsbedi?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a slightly different setup, but the key is in simply realizing that `flask_pymongo.PyMongo` is a wrapper of an instance of `PyMongo` that you can access directly.
In this case, that PyMongo instance is located in `mongo.db`

```
with app.app_context():
  admin = admin.Admin(app)
  admin.add_view(UserView(mongo.db['users']))
```

You may or may not need to do `with app.app_context():` depending on your setup, but I figured it was worth leaving in.